# Python Seleinum finding a specific class of div, if another div is located within, then find a third div and copy the text within

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Scraping with selenium to see if I have unread messages.

I'll search based on the "master" div class that contains the DM link, text and the marker of if the message is unread. If the message is unread, a div class labelled "Bubble" will appear.  If the div marker identifying the message as being unread appears, then search within a sibling div for the username of the user.

Here is the xpath for the "master" DM:
div class = "Message"
/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]

Here is the xpath for the "Bubble" class that identifies if it's unread:
div class = "Bubble"
/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/a/div/div[3]

Here is the xpath for  the div class that contains the username:
div class = "Username"
html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/a/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
DMs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="Message"]')
for item in DMsNew:
    try:
        new = item.find_element_by_xpath('//a/div/div[3]')
        print("found")
        username = item.find_element_by_xpath('//a/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div')

    except:
        print("not found")
```

Issue that I am experiencing is that it ends up finding all the divs on the page that contain the bubble class rather than just comparing to see if the current div message section contains the unread div class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use . to access child xpaths. Otherwise your checking from root.

```
new = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a/div/div[3]')
username = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div')
```